# Rdlc Report in MVC Project being able to Switch databases

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, reporting-services, rdlc

I currently have an MVC project that im going to be able to be switching 3 databases depending on the group of people using it. The databases all have the same tables. 1 is for the global engineers, 1 is for local production and 1 is for local testing.
How should I have my rdlc reports so I can switch to a different database easily? I have my project so I just have to change a connectionstring in web.config and then the context in each controller. Then the database is changed. For a Rdlc report it will be a little harder than that, do I need to add another dataset and just have to change that? On my reports it only allows me to add 1 data source at a time but in the datasets I can have multiple and each 1 can point to its own connectionstring.

Comment: Are the 3 dbs on the same server? Are the reports on the same SSRS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to change the data source before report render. SSRS doesn’t play nice with MVC. You can try dotnet Report builder https://www.dotnetreport.com and see if it works for your requirements. Full disclosure, I’m affiliated with the company.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the connectionstring before logging in to know what database it would be but still needs its all are in the same server. sorry for my english :(